# Let's get critical: Jul 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Beer Stack Exchange](http://beer.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What characteristics does Becks have, and what are similar beers?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/889/what-characteristics-does-becks-have-and-what-are-similar-beers)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I try a wide variety beers without buying them by the case/spending a lot of money?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/814/how-can-i-try-a-wide-variety-beers-without-buying-them-by-the-case-spending-a-lo)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [In the United States, is a beer required to state ABV on the bottle/label?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/854/in-the-united-states-is-a-beer-required-to-state-abv-on-the-bottle-label)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to store a bottle of beer once it has been opened?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/862/how-to-store-a-bottle-of-beer-once-it-has-been-opened)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What transforms a beer into a Barley Wine?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/887/what-transforms-a-beer-into-a-barley-wine)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [I'm aging a few bottles. They've been in the fridge for a while. Should I take them out now?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/845/im-aging-a-few-bottles-theyve-been-in-the-fridge-for-a-while-should-i-take-t)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How do restaurants/businesses get their beer?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/840/how-do-restaurants-businesses-get-their-beer)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Removing the Crown / Neck paper](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/880/removing-the-crown-neck-paper)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Are there microbreweries or craft breweries in Iceland?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/835/are-there-microbreweries-or-craft-breweries-in-iceland)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Are there any craft beer or microbrewery in Washington and Baltimore?](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/865/are-there-any-craft-beer-or-microbrewery-in-washington-and-baltimore)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---